# How to wind back a commit using "hg revert"?

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I did a commit that I had to revert on my server because it wasn't working. I did "hg revert --all --rev 855" and stripped my changes from my Bitbucket and my local. When I did "hg update" and tried to pull the next changes I made I got "abort: crosses branches (use 'hg merge' to merge or use 'hg update -C' to discard changes)"

How can I go forward with just the wanted changes and lose the commits/heads?

Comment: Why is this posted with a "git" tag? In any case, `hg revert` means "set files back to a previous state", not "undo a commit". It's usually a bad idea to try to remove (`hg strip`) a published commit entirely; instead, you usually want to add a new commit that inverts the effect of a previous commit, which in Mercurial is done with `hg backout`.

Answer (score 4):

You want to do a `backout` not a `revert`.  First, clean up your working directory by removing any uncommitted files:

```
hg revert -a
```

Then remove the problematic commit using `backout`:

```
hg backout -r 855
```

You will be prompted for a commit message.  Save it and you're good to go.